# How to force WooCommerce shipping address to show in order emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I had to change the `shipping_address_1` field to another custom field because of payment gateway regulations with a limit of 60 characters only, so the woocommerce doesn't recognise that I'm shipping to another address, so it doesn't comes in emails, only the billing details.

How can I make it come in emails like regular?

I am using a custom checkout field plugin and have tried couple of online solutions with no success - I even tried code in functions.php but it seems it was for local pickup only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSCIo.jpg)
[image]

Comment: unfortunatly solution doesn't work, still receiving the emails without the shipping details as shown in the images